# How to make contact form multilanguage

Tags: php

So I have to make contact form multilingual, but im stuck for 7 hours already.
SO i have to make ajax ok/error messages without duplicating code.

```
 $language = $_GET["language"] OR $language == "en";
    $language = $_GET["language"] OR $language == "es";
    $language = $_GET["language"] OR $language == "pl";

    if ($language == "en") {
  $okMessage = 'Thank you, we will get back to you soon!';
  $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
}
if ($language == "pl") {
  $okMessage = 'Dziękujemy, skontaktujemy się niedługo';
  $errorMessage = 'W wiadomości pojawił się błąd, prosimy spróbować później';
}
if ($language == "es") {
  $okMessage = 'Gracias, nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto!';
  $errorMessage = 'Hubo un error al enviar la solicitud. Por favor intente de nuevo.';
}
```

So what i want my code to do is that when im on poland contact form page. like www.website.com/pl-contact-page.php?language=pl - it gives me error/success messages in poland

Comment: And what isn't working?  What's your specific question?

Comment: Use `==` or `===` on `if ($language = "pl")`

Comment: Well, when ever i submit poland contact form or english or spain, then it always givs me poland error since its last one at the group

Comment: Eddie, tried it does not work

Comment: `$_GET["language"] OR $language == "en";` seems like invalid syntax to me, not even sure what this that is supposed to do

Comment: Eddie, not it doesnt send contact form message

Comment: $_GET["language"] OR $language == "en"; how should i work it out? @GrumpyCrouton

Comment: `$language = isset($_GET["language"]) ? $_GET["language"] : "pl"`?

Comment: @Eddie Yes, that seems correct, but can be shortened further `$language = $_GET['language'] ?: 'pl';`

Comment: @user99122122 That wouldn't work out to anything, because it's invalid syntax. What is it meant to do? `$_GET['language']` OR `Compare $language to string`? If the `OR` is allowed there (And I don't think it is), then it could either be equal to `$_GET['language']` OR `true/false`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton i did like yours, but still gives me wrong language error...

Comment: if ($language === "en") {
  $okMessage = 'Thank you, we will get back to you soon!';
  $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
}
if ($language === "pl") {
  $okMessage = 'Dziękujemy, skontaktujemy się niedługo';
  $errorMessage = 'W wiadomości pojawił się błąd, prosimy spróbować później';
}
if ($language === "es") {
  $okMessage = 'Gracias, nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto!';
  $errorMessage = 'Hubo un error al enviar la solicitud. Por favor intente de nuevo.';
}

Comment: It gives me: Gracias, nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto!

Comment: When I am on poland page

Comment: this `if ($language = "pl") {` is assigning the value `pl` not comparing. It should either be `==` or `===`

Comment: What is `$language = $_GET["language"] OR $language == "en";` supposed to do ?

Comment: @Cid I am so weak at php, but it should add tag to the url like. www.website.com/en-contact-form.php?language=en, and it should give me now contact form error messages in english

Comment: @user99122122: That line of code doesn't add anything to the URL.  It assigns a value to the variable `$language`.  When you debug, what value is being assigned?  What value do you expect to be assigned?  Why?

Comment: @David So what i want my code to do is that when im on poland contact form page. like www.website.com/pl-contact-page.php?language=pl - it gives me error/success messages in poland - but ?language=pl is custom url

Comment: @user99122122: You've effectively described what you want to happen, but you haven't described what the problem is.  The code you originally posted had a typo which was pointed out to you, and now that you've changed that code you've effectively changed the question.  So what's the new question?  What specifically isn't working in your code?  This is a good chance to familiarize yourself with some basic debugging in PHP.  Which line of code is producing an unexpected result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Comment: @David problem is, that it gives me everytime the same success message, which is: 'Gracias, nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto! - even when i am on poland page, it gives me spain message, and even on english page

Comment: @David I expect that every contact form page has its own language success message

Comment: @user99122122: Then, according to your code, clearly `$language == "es"` is true.  There have been a variety of comments above suggesting changes to how you set that variable.  You haven't changed it.  ***Debug*** and ***observe*** the value of your `$language` variable.  See how each operation changes that value.  Given the description and the code changes in the question so far, it also seems very unlikely that the code you're showing us is exactly your code in the first place.

Comment: @David I did exactly and edited my code, but still it doesnt load other success messages on their right language page

Comment: [UpVote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qq7YZ.png) [Mark Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB3cT.png) as you can see you can vote and mark the answer according to the pictures..

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

After reading this thread I decided to give my little help, I changed a bit your code to get it more easy and secure... what that you need is [Query String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) and [Parse String](https://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)... the rest is simple... I tested on my localtest and works fine...

```
<?php
  @ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
  $gurl = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $ourl = array();
  parse_str($gurl, $ourl);
  if (isset($ourl['language']) || (!empty($ourl['language']))) {
    $language = htmlspecialchars($ourl['language'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    if ($language == "en") {
      $okMessage = 'Thank you, we will get back to you soon!';
      $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';
    } elseif ($language == "pl") {
      $okMessage = 'Dziekujemy, skontaktujemy sie niedlugo';
      $errorMessage = 'W wiadomosci pojawil sie blad, prosimy spróbowac pózniej';
    } elseif ($language == "es") {
      $okMessage = 'Gracias, nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto!';
      $errorMessage = 'Hubo un error al enviar la solicitud. Por favor intente de nuevo';
    }
    // echo $okMessage; #Debug purpose
    // echo $errorMessage; #Debug purpose
  } else {
    echo ("No language available!");
  }
?>
```

Version with my function `get_messages()` that detect the correct string code (`UTF-8` or `ANSI`):

```
<?php
  @ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
  $gurl = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  $ourl = array();
  parse_str($gurl, $ourl);
  if (isset($ourl['language']) || (!empty($ourl['language']))) {
    $language = htmlspecialchars($ourl['language'], ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    function get_messages($string) {
      return mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($string, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
    }
    if ($language == "en") {
      $okMessage = get_messages('Thank you, we will get back to you soon!');
      $errorMessage = get_messages('There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later');
    } elseif ($language == "pl") {
      $okMessage = get_messages('Dziekujemy, skontaktujemy sie niedlugo');
      $errorMessage = get_messages('W wiadomosci pojawil sie blad, prosimy spróbowac pózniej');
    } elseif ($language == "es") {
      $okMessage = get_messages('Gracias, nos pondremos en contacto con usted pronto!');
      $errorMessage = get_messages('Hubo un error al enviar la solicitud. Por favor intente de nuevo');
    }
    // echo $okMessage; #Debug purpose
    // echo $errorMessage; #Debug purpose
  } else {
    echo ("No language available!");
  }
?>
```

`http://localhost-test/contact-page.php?language=pl`

`http://localhost-test/contact-page.php?language=en`

`http://localhost-test/contact-page.php?language=es`

`http://localhost-test/contact-page.php`

Notes: you have to `echo` somewhere your messages otherwise the code appears not working well...

I hope this helps.